# C# Removing Tabs from Readline Input

Tags: c#

I am inputting lines using the StreamReader's ReadLine. However for user friendliness in terms of reading the files outside of the program, I want to add tabbing. But I need to remove any tabbing when the files are being read in the program.

How can this be achieved? I have considered using Trim but I don't know if that will work.

Comment: Where are the tabs in the strings? What do you want to be there instead?

Comment: Instead of just considering something, try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`string.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) with the specified characters if you want starting and trailing tabs:

```
var trimmed = streamReader.ReadLine().Trim('\t');
```

Or [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) if tabs are also in the middle:

```
string trimmed = Regex.Replace(lineWithTabs, @"\t", "");
```

Comment: This only works if the tabs are in front or at the back of the string, right?

Comment: But does the \t have to be in the string or will the Trim assume it is looking for any tab?

Comment: @germi Yes, it will trim front and end.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. No error but it is not removing the tabs. I will produce an output to find out what the string looks like

Comment: @JeremyBeare See my edit regarding the Regex option.

Comment: The Regex option threw errors but I managed to get the Trim option to work with a bit of tweaking. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("path");
fileContent = fileContent.Replace('\t', ' ');
```

Of course that works also for every line returned by `ReadLine`.